# Problem with loading email addresses from accounts.json file in Python script

Tags: javascript, python, json

I'm having trouble with a Python script that is supposed to load email addresses from an accounts.json file and paste them into a form. However, when I run the script, it is not pasting the email addresses, it is pasting "YOUR EMAIL", literally. I've already edited the accounts.json file with the correct email addresses, but the script is still not working.

I've tried adding a print() statement to the loadAccounts() function to verify that the ACCOUNTS variable contains the correct email addresses, but it doesn't seem to be displaying the email addresses correctly.

Here's the code for the loadAccounts() function: (It is a PY file, I do copy as path and I run the file with "Python *file directory*. It runs successfully but the above issue is annoying.

```
def loadAccounts():
    global ACCOUNTS
    if ARGS.accounts:
        ACCOUNTS = []
        for account in ARGS.accounts:
            ACCOUNTS.append({"username": account.split(":")[0], "password": account.split(":")[1]})
    else:
        try:
            ACCOUNTS = json.load(open("accounts.json", "r"))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            with open("accounts.json", 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps([{
                    "username": "Your Email",
                    "password": "Your Password"
                }], indent=4))
            prPurple(f"""
        [ACCOUNT] Accounts credential file "accounts.json" created.
        [ACCOUNT] Edit with your credentials and save, then press any key to continue...
            """)
            input()
            ACCOUNTS = json.load(open("accounts.json", "r"))
```

Here is the email.json

```
[
  {
    "username": "My outlook email address",
    "password": "My password"
  },
  {
    "username": "My gmail account",
    "password": "My password"
  }
]
```

The github repo said "Modify the email.json.sample file with your Gmail email login credentials. To obtain the required password, go to https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords after enabling two-factor authentication, and rename the password file by deleting ".sample" at the end. Additionally, you can disable specific alerts in this file if desired."

so I edidted email.json

```
[
  {
    "sender": "MY@gmail.com",
    "password": "MY APP PASSWORD",
    "receiver": "receiver@example.com", (DIDN'T CHANGE ANYTHING FOR RECIEVER)
    "withdrawal": "true",
    "lock": "true",
    "ban": "true",
    "phoneverification": "true",
    "proxyfail": "false"
  }
]
```

I tried adding this to my code but didn't work, in the py file

```
 # Print the ACCOUNTS variable to verify that it contains the correct email addresses
        print("ACCOUNTS:", ACCOUNTS)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You are literally writing the unwanted content into your `accounts.json` here:

```
with open("accounts.json", 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps([{
                    "username": "Your Email",
                    "password": "Your Password"
                }], indent=4))
```

Why do that, if you don't want to do that?

#### Why are you telling us what you put in `email.json`?

That file does not get read anywhere in your code.

#### Step 1. Put this in `accounts.json`, not `email.json`

```
[
  {
    "username": "My outlook email address",
    "password": "My password"
  },
  {
    "username": "My gmail account",
    "password": "My password"
  }
]
```

#### Step 2. Remove the code that overwrites `accounts.json`

That code was trying to be helpful, by creating a dummy file if the file does not exist, but it is unfortunately just creating confusion. You are knowledgeable enough to create an `accounts.json` file manually, which will eliminate this type of problem.

Try reducing your code to this:

```
def loadAccounts():
    global ACCOUNTS
    if ARGS.accounts:
        ACCOUNTS = []
        for account in ARGS.accounts:
            ACCOUNTS.append({"username": account.split(":")[0], "password": account.split(":")[1]})
    else:
        try:
            ACCOUNTS = json.load(open("accounts.json", "r"))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Please create an `accounts.json` file and try again.")
```

Comment: sorry, i am new to all this, so do i remove this from py file?, and sorry about the email.json

Comment: Remove what?  We can't understand why you are surprised at finding `"Your Email"` in your output file, when that is LITERALLY what you are writing.  Instead of writing `"Your Email"`, you need to write the username field from the `account` record you just read.

Comment: Tim I think it his code is not intending to write back the value it read; rather, it is writing a default set of values, if the reading process failed due to File-not-found.

Comment: i am so sorry for the confusion,  didn't write this, this is a GitHub repo. i have no coding experience and i am trying my best to understand all of this. I appreciate you explaining this to me

Comment: I am still getting the error after pasting your suggestion @Eureka

Comment: You may indeed have too little coding experience to solve this problem, because you will have left out some information that you considered unimportant or did not even know existed. For example, if _despite carrying out both steps above_, the problem is that the email is still being set to "Your Email", then the accounts.json file you have edited is not the accounts.json file that is being used by the program. Search your computer and you will find another one. The _working directory_ of python is not what you (and therefore we) thought it was.